# vue/nuxt SPA takes several seconds until first XHR/axios request to backend

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I have an SPA built in nuxt2/vue2 that is becoming unusable. I noticed that it takes up to 5 seconds until the first request to the backend happens. Here is the network tab with the waterfall. The last request is the first actual request to the API:

[image]

It seems that the SPA itself takes much too long to load. Here are my suggestions on what I will look into:

- moving the files to a CDN (they are currently hosted on the same
  server as the backend)
- Checking the webserver caching settings. (Why
  does it need to load all those files everytime?)
- Checking the bundle
  chunks itself. (Does it need all the code or could is something wrong with the splitting and treeshaking)

**My main question is:**
What should I focus on first and did I miss anything that could be the cause for the time until the first api request?

Comment: Code splitting/lazy loading/lazy hydration/reducing the bundle size of JS/CSS/not loading the material icons 3 times/etc, a lot of stuff can make an SPA take time to load.